# "Unable to merge dex" Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex

I read a lot other topics, but none of them helped me.
I wrote this project 2 months ago and at that time everything worked fine. Now I opened it again and it writes:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Here is my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.szabo.organizer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the project gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I changed all "compile" to "implementation", I deleted .gradle directory, I tried clean project and rebuild, I tried Invalidate and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

Instead of this

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for me. Can you explain why it is so? Just to be able to solve the problem in the future.

Comment: @SzabóBotond-Ferenc please read this it will solve your doubt https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android